# "he was coding inside Microsoft Office Suite."

Tags: sentence-meaning

This is from [a *TIME* article](https://time.com/6158182/vitalik-buterin-ethereum-profile/).

> Instead, Vitalik gravitated to the clarity of numbers. At 4, he
> inherited his parents’ old IBM computer and started playing around
> with Excel spreadsheets. At 7, he could recite more than a hundred
> digits of pi, and would shout out math equations to pass the time. By
> 12, **he was coding inside Microsoft Office Suite**.

From what I saw on the Internet, The Microsoft Office Suite is a set of programs for common productivity tasks, including a word processing program, a spreadsheet tool, presentation software, an email program and others.

Then, does the part in bold in the above context mean Vitalik used programming languages to create or improve some parts of Microsoft Office Suite?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you very much.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: I completely forgot about Visual Basic for Applications ('VBA') which is a programming language and coding environment. It is a version of Microsoft Visual Basic supplied 'inside' Microsoft Office, and is especially used to automate tasks in Excel (the spreadsheet Office application) and to provide functions not easily obtainable using the standard Excel features. It is particularly oriented towards arithmetic and number-crunching. This completely negates my comment above. Apologies.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Oh, I got it. I really appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Office includes Visual Basic for Applications ('VBA') which is a programming language and coding environment. It is a version of Microsoft Visual Basic.

VBA is supplied 'inside' Microsoft Office, in the sense that a user has to start an Office application (typically Excel or Access) and then find VBA. It is often used to automate tasks or provide functions not easily obtainable using the standard Office app's features. Many Office users never see VBA and are unaware of its existence. It can be used for general purpose programming and data-processing tasks, although it may be found cumbersome compared with a more general-purpose programming environment.

[Visual Basic for Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications)

Comment: Thank you very much.